# TableViewController has no member 'View'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am using a Cocoapod - SAConfettiView (https://cocoapods.org/pods/SAConfettiView) so my app would display confetti when an item from a list is checked. However, I am getting an error, I tried to search for an answer but I don't understand exactly what is the problem.

This is the code :

```
Class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

     let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
     //other stuff
}
```

and the error showing on the 2nd line of the code is :

> Value of type '(TableViewController) -> () -> TableViewController' has
>   no member 'view'

so what can I do to solve the problem and how should I use SAConfetti pod? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view you want to access might be inside the tableview cell. So a better way is you can try to access the view inside the cell for a row at method. Or you can create the outlet for the view inside the cell class and then use it.

```
let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: cell.view.bounds)
```